# Still can not build android_tutorial_camera

Tags: android-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying on and off for more than a week to get the android core projects built. I need to send video from my android phone over ros. Every time I have followed the ros java and android tutorials to a T, but attempting to build the tutorials gives me:

> Build Failed: Could not find any version that matches org.ros.rosjava_bootstrap:gradle_plugins:[0.1,0.2]

I have found the exact same question asked on ros answers, but none of the other suggestions (change the groovy version, catkin_make the workspace, etc) work. Can anyone help me with this or suggest an alternate way of obtaining the ros android camera apk?

Edit: After looking around, I've found multiple versions of instructions on what to do to build the android_core tutorials. After installing rosjava and android studio/apk, what do I do? Do I simply import the project, or catkin_make the specific tutorial and source its setup.bash?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197056/still-can-not-build-android_tutorial_camera/) by [mango](https://answers.ros.org/users/20627/mango/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You do a catkin_make and, if that goes OK, you can import the project into android studio.  Make sure you are using only android studio version 0.6.1, otherwise the repo fails.  Also, looks like you may have a typo in the build.gradle file in your android_core directory, there is a bracket " ]" in your line instead of a parentheses ")"

In that file, under dependencies, you should have

classpath group: 'org.ros.rosjava_bootstrap', name: 'gradle_plugins', version: '[0.1,0.2)'

You may also need to add this dependency:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'

See this question and answer for details:
http://answers.ros.org/question/199283/ros-tango-samples-dont-run/

---

Originally posted by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) with karma: 875 on 2014-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0